# New-AzSqlDatabaseImport requires a storage account access key, cannot be authenticated through Entra ID

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, microsoft-entra-id

I am using the Az PowerShell command [`New-AzSqlDatabaseImport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseimport?view=azps-11.0.0) to create a fresh Azure SQL test database from a `testdb.bacpac` as part of my Azure DevOps deployment pipeline.

`testdb.bacpac` is stored as a blob in a Storage Account, and the command is able to access it using an access key, but I've now decided to disable account key access on the storage account for security reasons.

So, now the only way to access storage is through Entra ID and RBAC, but [`New-AzSqlDatabaseImport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseimport?view=azps-11.0.0) doesn't seem to support that. What other options do I have for importing this bacpac?

Comment: You can make use SAS token authentication instead of access key authentication.

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to check the suggestion below? If the answer works for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you may use the [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli#download-a-blob) command in the `AzureCLI@2` pipeline task to download `testdb.bacpac` file from your storage account into the `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` on the pipeline agent and then import the `testdb.bacpac` with the help of the task `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1`. Here is a sample for your reference.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az storage blob download `
          --account-name $(storageAccountName) `
          --container-name $(containerName) `
          --name testdb.bacpac `
          --file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testdb.bacpac `
          --auth-mode login
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: '$(serverName).database.azure.com'
    DatabaseName: 'NewDB-$(Build.BuildId)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Import'
    BacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testdb.bacpac'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

Bothe the `AzureCLI@2` task and `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` task authenticate against the underlying service principal (with `Client Id` and `secret`) which is referenced by the ARM service connection. Therefore, please make sure the service principal has sufficient permissions to access the storage account and to administer the SQL server.

The `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` task is basically using [SQLPackage tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#use-sqlpackage) to import from the BACPAC file.

[image]

Hope the information helps.

Comment: Due to our specific use case we had to use `New-AzSqlDatabaseImport` rather than `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment`, but your tip about `az storage blob download` led me to find `az storage blob generate-sas` which I was able to use to generage a user delegation SAS which are appartently the only type of SAS allowed when you disable account key access on a storage account.